# Concrete category of topological spaces over preordered sets: what are the initial morphisms?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

I am reading [The Joy of Cats](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf) to become more familiar with category theory and I came upon the following question on concrete categories.

Let **Top** be the category of topological spaces and let **Prost** be the category of preordered sets, with monotone maps as morphisms. Since every topological space is equipped with the [specialization preorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specialization_(pre)order) and since a continuous function is monotone with respect to this preorder, there is a natural forgetful functor from **Top** to **Prost**.

I now consider **Top** as a concrete category over **Prost**.
According to *The Joy of Cats* (p. 134), a morphism $f: X \to Y$ in **Top** is called *initial* if for each topological space $Z$ and for each monotone map $g: Z \to X$, the condition $f \circ g$ continuous implies $g$ continuous.

It is not difficult to see that any continuous map $f: X \to Y$, 
where $X$ is equipped with the initial topology defined by $f$, is an initial morphism.

**Question**. Is the converse true? If not, what are the initial morphisms in this case?

N.B. The converse is true if **Top** is considered as a concrete category over **Set**, but this case is different.

Answer (score 2):

My colleague *Mai Gehrke* found a positive answer to my question: if $f : X \to Y$ is an initial morphism of **Top** over **Prost**, then $X$ is equipped with the [initial topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology) defined by $f$.

**Proof**. Let $f: X \to Y$ be an initial map.

**Step 1**. Let $x,y \in X$. If $f(x) \leqslant f(y)$, then $x \leqslant y$.

Consider the [cofinite topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology) on $\mathbb{N}$ and let $g: \mathbb{N} \to X$ be the map defined by $g(0) = x$ and
$g(n) = y$ if $n > 0$. Since the specialization order defined by the cofinite topology is the equality relation, $g$ is a monotone map. Let $h = f \circ g$. Then $h(0) = f(x)$ and $h(n) = f(y)$ if $n > 0$. I claim that $h$ is continuous. Indeed, let $U$ be an open subset of $Y$. Since $f(x) \leqslant f(y)$, the condition $f(x) \in U$ implies $f(y) \in U$. It follows that $h^{-1}(U)$ is either equal to $\emptyset$, $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{N} - \{0\}$ and hence is open in all cases, which proves the claim. Since $f$ is an initial map and $g$ is monotone, $g$ is continuous. Thus if $V$ is an open subset of $X$ containing $x$, $g^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{N}$ containing $0$. Therefore $g^{-1}(V)$ is cofinite and contains some $n > 0$. It follows that $y = g(n)$ belongs to $V$. Thus any open subset containing $x$ also contains $y$, that is, $x \leqslant y$.

**Step 2**. Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the topology on $X$ and let $\mathcal{I}$ be the initial topology on $X$ defined by $f$. Since $f$ is continuous, $\mathcal{I} \subseteq \mathcal{S}$. Let $i: (X, \mathcal{I}) \to (X, \mathcal{S})$ be the identity map. Then $f \circ i:(X, \mathcal{I}) \to Y$ is continuous by definition of the initial topology. Moreover, suppose that $x \leqslant_\mathcal{I} y$. Since $f \circ i$ is continuous, it is monotone with respect to the specialization orders and hence $f(x) \leqslant f(y)$. It follows by Step 1 that $x \leqslant_\mathcal{T} y$. Thus $i: (X, \mathcal{I}) \to (X, \mathcal{S})$ is monotone and since $f$ is initial and $f \circ i$ is continuous, $i$ is a continuous map from $(X, \mathcal{I})$ to $(X, \mathcal{S})$. It follows that $\mathcal{S} \subset \mathcal{I}$ and finally
$\mathcal{S} = \mathcal{I}$. Thus the topology on $X$ is the initial topology defined by $f$.